# Offset year with Pandas Dataframe DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, offset

I want to add +1 year to each date in my dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_market)

df = df[(df['calendardate'] > '2001-12-31')]
df = df[['ticker','calendardate','marketcap']]
```

This doesn't work:

```
df.calendardate = df.calendardate + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Gives me:

```
TypeError: must be str, not relativedelta
```

Comment: `df.calendardate += pd.Timedelta(years=1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that will raise an error, but you could use `days=365`

Comment: @COLDSPEED Raises `ValueError: cannot construct a Timedelta from the passed arguments, allowed keywords are [weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds].`

@sacul Raises `TypeError: must be str, not Timedelta`

Comment: @HelloToEarth, I think that your column is the wrong dtype. Try `df.calendardate = pd.to_datetime(df.calendardate)`, and then either the `Timedelta` solution or your `DateOffset` solution should work.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks!